# I am facing a problem redirecting to a url. It is throwing an error No routes matched location "/login/shipping"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, frontend, react-router-dom

this the code I am using to redirect:-

```
const checkoutHandler = () => {
    navigate('/login?redirect=shipping')
  };
```

Even when I am logged-in, it's redirecting to localhost:3000/login/shipping where else it should redirect to localhost:3000/shipping

what changes should I make? should I put a if-else to check for logged in person or do something else?
[This](https://github.com/niruparekh09/shopee-website/blob/main/frontend/src/screens/CartScreen.js) my code

Comment: FWIW your app code isn't rendering a route for `path="/shipping"` either, so you'll need to add that after you fix the redirect issue.